# How do I reduce over 1000 links programatically in a jump menu?

Tags: css, wordpress, menubar

Ok, so maybe my search syntax is wrong here, this could have very well been covered in stackoverflow but i've been unable to find anything after hours of searching.  Be warned, I am a novice developer when it comes to this type of stuff and would appreciate any guidance, help or pointers to accomplish the goal.  I'm open to suggestions of any type! :)

So, I have a site http://www.animetip.com

On this site we have a popular feature called a "jump menu" which allows a user to quickly navigate directly to the page which contains the anime series they would like to see an episode in.  Essentially we have every series on the site (over 1000) broken down in an a-z list.  When a user hovers over a letter, the menu will drop down and display all series that begin with that letter.  A user can then go to the series they'd like to view and click on it to go directly to the page.

The issue with this is SEO.  We are being penalized due to the number of links on the page.  What we need to accomplish is the same (or better) functionality while reducing the links loaded in the page.  If we could come up with a way to create the menu and have the link itself not be served until its clicked on I believe that would resolve the issue.

What is the best strategy for doing this?  I am no expert by any means, but I was thinking that putting all the links in mySQL and then calling the link as its clicked would be ok, but a friend cautioned me that it would cause a performance hit. I have also reviewed material which indicates you can do the same thing using an array to store the links and then call them as they are needed using PHP.  I grasp the concept of doing that but could use a stub type example to get me started.

The site is built on Wordpress with a completely custom template / theme.

Someone has commented that the topic wasn't researched.  Unfortunately I've spent lots of time researching it, the problem is that I think I'm using the wrong terminology to describe what I need to find.  If anyone would care to give me the terminology or a good place to conduct further research (even a few keywords!) I will be MORE than happy to go do that.

Thank you for any help or tips to information I can learn from!

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using ajax so that the links are not visible in the actual source code and while clicking the a,b,c links it will call a separate php file and display the output from the db on the fly. I hope this will resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vasanthan!  I'll give that a shot tonight and let you guys know how it goes.